# What is isolated thread in webworkers?

Tags: web-worker

What is isolated thread? 
I found it following article.

```
Web Workers run in an isolated thread. As a result, the code that they execute needs to be contained in a separate file.
```

[isolated thread](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)

Normally, threads are subset of processes. So I am wondering how they are isolated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're isolated in the sense that they don't share the same JavaScript global execution context as the main page's JavaScript. The only way they can interact with the page's main (UI) JavaScript is by sending and receiving messages (`postMessage` and the associated `message` event).

Here's an example demonstrating that the worker operates with a different global context:

`page.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Isolated Worker</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
// A global variable
var answer = 42;
(function() {

    // We see answer
    display("UI: typeof answer = " + typeof answer);

    // Worker doesn't
    var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        display(e.data);
    };

    function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`worker.js`:

```js
this.postMessage("Worker: typeof answer = " + typeof answer);
```

Output:

```
UI: typeof answer = number
Worker: typeof answer = undefined
```

As you can see, the worker can't see the main page's globals; they're in different global execution contexts.